# Return to Main Activity from arbitrary Activity on android application

Tags: java, android

I'm developing an android application which have a kind of action bar and a dashboard.

When the user click the "application logo" button on the ActionBar from any Activity in the application,
it would then open the dashboard activity. And finish all others Activities behind it.

What is the best way to do that, if I just start the new Dasboard Activity,
then how could I finish others activities behind it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

use `startActivity(intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));`

Comment: Thanks, I just about thinking some complicated way. but your answer save me :)

Comment: You'll probably also want to use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` for your purposes.  I use both flags together in my app to accomplish what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

One way to finish all activities in stack above another activity is as follows:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Test1.this,Test2.class);             
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

After this you can type:

```
startActivity(intent);
```

This will finish all activities above Test2.